# Jquery: Como destacar alguns números em negrito dentro de uma sequência numérica de 0 a 99 após um click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma sequência numérica de 0 a 99:

0
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
99

No caso estou tentando colocar alguns números em negrito após clicar em um botão. Por exemplo, dentro de um primeiro input tiver o número 2 e dentro de um segundo input tiver o número 99, e após ter clicado em um botão, o número 2 e o 99 ficam em negrito conforme abaixo:

0
1
**2**
3
4
5
.
.
.
**99**

A princípio estou tentando com o seguinte código html e um script em jquery para aplicar está solução, porém não estou conseguindo dar uma melhorada nele para chegar no resultado final:

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="number" id="campo1" value="2"/>
<br>
<input type="number" id="campo2" value="99"/>
<br>
<button type="button" id="getBtn">Destacar números</button>
<br>

<div id="sequencia"></div>
```

**Script para chamar o evento click:**

```
$('#getBtn').on( "click", function() {

  var campo1 = $('#campo1').val();
  var campo2 = $('#campo2').val();

// A partir deste ponto, não sei como aprimorar o código

for(let i = 0;i <= 100;i++){
    console.log(i);
}

});
```

No caso como eu posso aprimorar meu script para chegar em uma solução viável?

Answer (score -1):

Solução encontrada baseando-me neste tópico:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77561058/jquery-how-to-highlight-some-numbers-in-bold-within-a-numeric-sequence-from-0-t

Conforme na questão acima, criei um array de strings para identificar os números dentro dos inputs marcando-os em negrito após o clique no botão:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('#getBtn').click(function(e) {
  const vals = $('input[type=number][id^=campo]').map((i, el) => el.valueAsNumber).get();
  const seq = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    seq.push(vals.includes(i) ? `<strong>${i}</strong>` : i);
  $("#sequencia").html(seq.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="campo1" value="2" />
<br>
<input type="number" id="campo2" value="99" />
<br>
<button type="button" id="getBtn">Identificar</button>
<br>
<div id="sequencia"></div>
```